# Android: ListView Load gives Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, simplecursoradapter

I'm trying to get data from sqlite to listview so i followed the example in the answer in this url 
[Make listview from SQLite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466396/make-listview-from-sqlite-database)

the CustomCursorAdapter is going like that

```
    public class CustomCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter  {
    private int layout; 
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    public CustomCursorAdapter (Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.layout = layout;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }


    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.topics, parent, false);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
                //1 is the column where you're getting your data from
        String name = c.getString(1);
        /**
         * Next set the name of the entry.
         */
        TextView name_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listLabel);
        if (name_text != null) {
            name_text.setText(name);
        }   
    }
}
```

but onCreate i have this code

```
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.layout.topics);
    connectToDB();
    from = new String[] { "topicTitle" };
    to = new int[] { R.id.listLabel };

    CustomCursorAdapter adapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.topics, cursor, from, to);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

with xml as follows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listLogo"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listLabel"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="15sp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

the problem is .. listView is Null!! .. which i don't know why!!

Comment: post your logcat error.

Comment: Have you set ContentView before getting listview reference

Comment: And where's the ListView in your layout?

Comment: And where in xml your ListView??

Comment: are you looking for custom listview with a image and textview for each roe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are refering to your layout topics. You should have a listview defined in xml with a id.
In your activity onCreate() after setCOntentView(R.layout.topics), fins the id of listview and set adapter to your list.

In your xml say topics.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#0095FF">
   <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" 
    android:id="@+id/lv">
   </ListView>
    // other ui elements
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your activity onCreate()

```
   setContentview(R.layout.topics);
   ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
   connectToDB();
   from = new String[] { "topicTitle" };
   to = new int[] { R.id.listLabel };


   CustomCursorAdapter adapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(this,
        R.layout.topics, cursor, from, to);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

From the discussion in chat

EDIT:

Define main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#0095FF">

<ListView android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
android:dividerHeight="8dp" 
android:divider="#000000" 
android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your activivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 ListView lv;
 CustomCursorAdapter cus;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    cus= new CustomCursorAdapter(parameters);
    lv.setAdapter(cus);

 }
 }
```

Define customCursor adapter inflate a custom layout. Set image for image view and text for textview.

Comment: your solution gives me error 
04-09 08:24:23.687: E/AndroidRuntime(26971): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 08:24:23.687: E/AndroidRuntime(26971): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thedarkdimension.StrangeInfo/com.thedarkdimension.StrangeInfo.Topics}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #9: You must supply a layout_height attribute.

Comment: @MohamedEmadHegab udated my answer. While copy pasting the xml code i missed the listview height. add android:layout_height="100dp" to your listview. Mention the height in dp or fill_parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp" 
android:id="@+id/main"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/listLogo"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listLabel"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="15sp" >
</TextView>

<ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/topics"
        ></ListView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

In Activity onCreate

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.layout.topics);
    connectToDB();
    from = new String[] { "topicTitle" };
    to = new int[] { R.id.listLabel };

    CustomCursorAdapter adapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.topics, cursor, from, to);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: your solution gives me error at setContentView
04-09 08:24:23.687: E/AndroidRuntime(26971): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 04-09 08:24:23.687: E/AndroidRuntime(26971): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thedarkdimension.StrangeInfo/com.thedarkdimension.StrangeInfo.‌​Topics}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #9: You must supply a layout_height attribute. –

Comment: @MohamedEmadHegab I updated my answer. Don't forget about LinearLayout id.

Comment: i think setContentView(R.layout.main); will be 
setContentView(R.layout.topics); also

Comment: now it tells me (Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list)

Comment: No! setContentView(R.layout.main), because your main layout is LinearLayout, and it's id android:id="@+id/main" - check my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27832/discussion-between-mohamed-emad-hegab-and-jimpanzer)